# asp net core entity framework - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

The following code:

```
public async static Task<List<RecentTask>> GetRecentTasks(ApplicationDbContext db,
    int EmployeeID, int NewTaskID, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    var TaskList = await db.RecentTask.ToListAsync(); // without this line - no exception

    var t = new RecentTask();
    t.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
    t.TaskDefinitionID = NewTaskID;
    db.RecentTask.Add(t);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // EXCEPTION!

    return TaskList;
}
```

causes the exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
>   disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
>   then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances. Object name:
>   'ApplicationDbContext'.

Removing the first line would cause the exception to disappear. I don't see how the object `db` would be disposed. Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?